# Strcat two unsigned char in C

Tags: c, string

I am currently trying to use strcat on two unsigned char but I keep getting a warning. Here is what I have for strcat:

```
unsigned char A[100],B[100];
A[0] = '1';
B[0] = '2';
strcat(A,B);
```

I am trying to put them togther so that I get A as the combination of both of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post the warning you are getting?

Comment: Do you need to initialise the rest of the array? Also should you assign the result to something?

Comment: Add `A[1] = B[1] = '\0';` then it will work. `strcat` assumes a few things. Also make sure to cast the arguments.

Comment: How to ask a better question: change *I keep getting a warning* to the specific warning message.

Comment: strcat only stops when it reachs a NUL string termination character, both for the source string and for the destination string.  Neither of the arrays 'A[]' nor 'B[]'  currently have a string NUL termination character (in this case at A[1] and B[1], so strcat will keep looking for the end of the A[] string, even if that string is not within the bounds of the A[] array.  Then it will append the characters in the B[] array until is encounters a NUL termination char even if that character is not within the bounds of the B[] array.   I.E. this is undefined behaviour leading to a seg fault event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strcpy(A,"1");
strcpy(B,"2");
strcat((char *)A,(char *)B);
```

You are just initilizing the first character in the array and not the `char array`

Else you can

```
char A[100] = "";
char B[100] = "";
```

and later you can have

```
char A[0] = '1';
char B[0] = '2';
```

strcat() protoype is

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

So the passed type should be `char *`

Answer (score 3):

The warning is because you are passing `unsigned char*` into a function that is meant for `char*`.

If you want to copy unsigned char, you should be using [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/).

```
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    unsigned char A[100],B[100];
    A[0] =  '1';
    B[0] =  '2';
    memcpy(A + 1, B, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is about concatenation, not copying.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char* ustrcat(unsigned char *dest, const unsigned char *src) {
  unsigned int length_1 = 0;
  unsigned int length_2 = 0;
  // find the end of the first unsigned char string
  for (; dest[length_1] != '\0'; length_1++);
  //input unsigned chars into the string from that position to the end
  for (; src[length_2] != '\0'; length_2++)
    dest[length_1+length_2] = src[length_2];
  // place a NULL terminating character at the end
  dest[length_1+length_2] = '\0';
  return dest;
}

int main(){
  unsigned char A[100] = "",B[100] = "";
  A[0] = '1';
  B[0] = '2';
  ustrcat(A,B);
  printf("%s\n", A);
  return 0;
}
```

Basically I just rewrote the strcat function for unsigned char type

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char A[100]={0}, B[100]={0};  // initialize the array to end the strings

A[0] = '1';                            // initialize the two strings
B[0] = '2';

strcat(A,B);                           // and simply copy them
```

Comment: Won't solve the warning - it is is important to null-terminate the strings, though.

Answer (score 0):

`char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three separate types. That means you can't pass an `unsigned char *` to a function expecting a `char *` without a cast. Either change to simple `char`:

```
char A[100], B[100];
```

or add casts in your `strcat()` call:

```
strcat((char *)A, (char *)B);
```

Also - don't forget to null-terminate those strings!

```
A[1] = 0;
B[1] = 0;
```

Comment: Can changing from char to unsigned char cause problems later in my program if there should be no negative values?

Comment: `char` might be an unsigned type already. That's why they are three different types. Use the one that's appropriate for your use case - for you that looks like `char`.

Comment: Im actually working with unsigned char because I am working on pixels in a picture and do not want any of them to go negative. Would that cause problems?

Comment: Why are you using `strcat` then? Can't you have 0-valued pixels? Use `memcpy` or `memmove` if they're more appropriate.

Comment: I am working on the LZW compression code and am trying to get the Previous = Previous + Current

Comment: `strcat` definitely won't work then - there could be 0-valued bytes in there anywhere. Do it the right way and keep track of where you are!

Comment: `memcopy` or `memmove`.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have never used them so I didn't think of that method.