# Concatenating char and string in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I'm playing with an Arduino board and the samples provided.  Trying to get a message I received to be displayed on the LCD.  I'm struggling to figure out how to work with some of the pre-built code.

I get the error: invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'const char*

I tried modify the `payload` parameter type but it breaks other references to MessageCallback.

Screen.print() definition in the documentation for the arduino board:
int print(unsigned int line, const char s, bool wrap)

Code:

```
static int  MessageCallback(const unsigned char *payload)
{
int result = 200;
const char screenMsg[100]; 
strcpy(screenMsg,"Set Temp: ");
strcat(screenMsg,payload);

Screen.print(1, screenMsg, true);

return result;
}
```

Comment: `const char screenMsg[100];` not initialized as const and then changed (?) in the next line seems ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strcat's arguments are `(char *, const char *)`. You can cast "payload" to a `char*` by doing "`strcat(screenMsg, (char*)payload);`". Read [Strcat two unsigned char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291676/strcat-two-unsigned-char-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

If you just change to `char screenMsg[100];` it should work.

The print function will not change the string you provide to it, is all that

> const char s

means.